# How to query for objects with certain enum flag on, using a db int to store it

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I have an object with a Flag enum with several possible "uses". The flag enum uses the proper power of 2.

Checking if a variable has a certain flag on, I can do it using the .NET 4 `HasFlag()`

BUT:

If I store that flag combination as a int in database...  how can I retrive the objects that have certain flag on using Entity Framework?

For example, if my object is a "`Contact`" type, I would like to query those of them that are actually "Customers and Friends", being Customers and Friends flags in the `ContactType` Enum.

Comment: How do you store a combination of enum values in DB?

Comment: @Tigran, just the int value of the enum combination of flags. Customer = 1 and Friend = 2... so the combination is 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt any ORM is going to have a way to adapt the HasFlags down to the appropriate SQL code for your DBMS.

What you are likely going to need to do is either write a stored procedure, or hand-crank the SQL Statement to be executed for this.

You don't mention what DBMS you're using - but if I assume you're using SQL Server, you are in luck as it has the [& (Bitwise AND) operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174965.aspx).

Practical example as T-SQL:

```
-- Setup Test Data 
DECLARE @Contacts TABLE (id int, contactType int, name nvarchar(MAX)) 

INSERT INTO @Contacts VALUES (1, 0, 'Fred'); -- Not Wanted
INSERT INTO @Contacts VALUES (2, 3, 'Jim');  -- Wanted
INSERT INTO @Contacts VALUES (3, 36, 'Mary');  -- Not wanted
INSERT INTO @Contacts VALUEs (4, 78, 'Jo');  -- Wanted

-- Execute Query
SELECT *
FROM @Contacts
WHERE ContactType & 2 = 2
```

Answer (score 6):

```
db.Contacts.Where(c => (c.Flag & MyEnum.Flag3) != 0).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the combined bit value as int and store that value in the db as a column here is a sample:

```
public enum MessagingProperties
{
    // No options selected (value is 0)
    None = 0x00,
    // messages are not discarded if subscriber is slow (value is 1)
    Durable = 0x01,
    // messages are saved to disk in case messaging crashes (value is 2)
    Persistent = 0x02,
    // messages are buffered at send/receive point so not blocking (value is 4)
    Buffered = 0x04
}
```

In order to combine these flag enums you do:

```
// combine the bit flags
var combinedFlags = MessagingProperties.Durable | MessagingProperties.Persistent | 
                     MessagingProperties.Buffered;

// this will be equal 7, no other combination can sum up to seven so it is unique, that's how bit flags work
int combinedFlagsInt = (int)combinedFlags;
```

You can now go ahead and store this value in the db. If you want to query for multiple bit flags you:

- combine them
- cast them into an int
- and use the resulting variable/value as a filter in the `Where` clause.

Comment: assume I stored in database the value "7" from your example. What if I want to filter all the messages with the flag "Durable". I don't think it can be done with a simple where clause, since there could be several int values that "hold" that flag.

Comment: @Romias correct, if this is what you are after you will have to store them in different fields

Comment: Thanks ntziolis... I will stay with several separate fields or I'll go with @Will Huges approach.